429 Error on readthedocs badge request using python requests
I am getting a 429 Too many requests response with a cloudflare human verification check from readthedocs when attempting access a relatively large number of badges such as https://readthedocs.org/projects/testing/badge/?version=latest. I can't seem to find any information about what backoff policy is sensible/if this has just recently be enforced. I don't think using the API will help me in this scenario but if that's what I should be using any advice would be appreciated!
def test_link(link: str, depth:int=0) -> bool:
    try:
        try:
            resp = requests.get(link)
        except:
            resp = requests.get(link, verify=False)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            return True
        elif resp.status_code == 429:
            print(f"Response from {link} too many requests, backing off - Error {resp.status_code}")
            time.sleep(10)
            if (depth >= 3):
                return test_link(link,depth+1)
            else:
                print("Too many retries, stopping")
        else:
            print(f"Response from {link} unsuccesful - Error {resp.status_code}")
            return False
    except SSLError as e:
        print("SSL version or cipher mismatch error occurred:", e)
        # Handle the error or continue with other operations
        return False
    except LocationParseError as e:
        print(f"Got {e} for {link}. It's most likely too long", len(link), " > 63")
        return False
    except ConnectionError as e:
        print(f"Got an error when connecting to {link}")
        print(e)
        return False


How many requests are you doing per second?
